# Help with Active Directory Structure

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory, exchange-2003

I came across an AD today where the previous admin had set it up in where every AD object is in a child OU of Domain Controllers..........

```
DOMAINNAME.LOCAL
     Builtin
     Computers
     Domain Controllers
           Active Users
           Computers
                      Servers
                      Workstations
           DistroGroups
.....
```

Tabs show that the OU is a child of the previous.

1. What should I keep in mind when moving the computers back to the proper OU?
2. What should I keep in mind when moving the other objects such as users and distrobution and security groups outside of the Domain Controller OU's child OU?

I will ensure GPO are properly applied to the correct OU but I am more concerned with effects this could have with our exchange 2003 server.....

Any one who has experience restructuring a improper AD structure please let me know your experience and issues in resolving matters such as these....

I understand in theory this may be OK but this is definitely not supported from microsoft and i have never seen ANYTHING like this....

For reference I came across this article. [ITWORLD AD ARTICLE](http://www.itworld.com/active-directory-mistake-nlswindows-080520?page=0%2C0)

Thanks,

This environment has one 2008 DC and two 2003 R2 DCs. They also have an Exchange 2003 Server. There are about 30 user workstations as well as a DFS system, RD Gateway, VPN, to name a few core services that may be effected by this.

Comment: Not sure why the guy made a big deal of that in that article. I've seen what he's describing as a supposed big problem in a number of large customer environments. The support boundary I'm familiar with is moving DCs out of the Domain Controllers OU all together.

Comment: After adjusting things ALOT of phantom issues have been miraculously resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, that's kinda crappy.  Here's what I would do...

1. Get intimately familiar with the current GPO structure.  If anything is going to break, it will be that.
2. Create a new structure in AD as you would like it organized.  Create the OUs and all that, and link the correct GPOs to that OU.
3. Move individual objects one at a time and test functionality as you go.  If something breaks, move it back and figure out what happened.  For critical servers/functions, schedule it after hours to reduce user impact.
4. Rinse and repeat.

I don't know if there's a magic bullet, but this is how I would approach it.

Comment: Also the 2008 DC when I click properties on a OU I cannot see the Group Policy tab. Only on the 2003 DCs... Any ideas?

Comment: To that last comment, Server 2008 has a separate MMC (Group Policy Management). Find it in Start -> Administrative Tools -> Group Policy Management.

Comment: AH! Thanks! Thought so but it was eluding me. +1

Comment: Thank you very much for this info. A fast and straight forward response.